# Looping for a sequence of steps in R

Tags: r

I was trying to write a short program that involves looping and got stuck.
My Code:

```
Screen=(rpois (1, lambda=3)) 
y=runif(Screen,0,1) 
Base=length(which(y<0.5 | y==0.5 )) 
SF=length(which(y>0.5)) 
Visits=cbind(Screen,Base,SF)
```

I want to generate simulations using poisson and then select values for the next level (Base in my case). My selection criteria is 0.5%. If Screen returns a value of 4, I would generate 4 random nos. between 0 and 1. Of these, I would count the nos. that have a value of less than or equal to 0. 5 and put it in Baseline. The rest will go to SF. I need to put this in a loop such that I get a table containing columns Screen,Base and SF and this would stop when the cumulative sum of values in Baseline reaches 100. So i would want the Screen to continue generating values till Base reaches 100.Sum of values of the column Base should be exactly 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your code in a while loop:

```
baseSum=0.0
Visits = NULL
while(baseSum < 100)
{
  Screen=(rpois (1, lambda=3)) 
  y=runif(Screen,0,1) 
  Base = length(which(y<=0.5))
  baseSum = baseSum + Base
  SF = Screen - Base
  Visits=rbind(Visits,c("Screen"=Screen,"BaseCount"=Base,"SFCount"=SF))    
}
plot(cumsum(Visits[,"BaseCount"]),type="b");grid()
sum(Visits[,"BaseCount"])
```

Or you can produce a lot of poisson samples and then cut off what you need:

```
tooManyRuns = t(sapply(rpois (110, lambda=3) , function(X) { y=runif(X,0,1); Base = length(which(y<=0.5)); SF = X-Base; return(c("Screen"=X,"BaseCount"=Base,"SFCount"=SF)) } ))
Visits =tooManyRuns[1:min(which(cumsum(tooManyRuns[,"BaseCount"])>=100.0)),]
plot(cumsum(Visits[,"BaseCount"]),type="b");grid()
sum(Visits[,"BaseCount"])
```

I assume you are doing a little experiment to see how many runs you would need under this transformation. If that is the case then you can wrap it like this:

```
numRunsNeeded = sapply(1:1000,
       function(...)
       {
        tooManyRuns = t(sapply(rpois (110, lambda=3) , function(X) { y=runif(X,0,1); Base = length(which(y<=0.5)); SF = X-Base; return(c("Screen"=X,"BaseCount"=Base,"SFCount"=SF)) } ))
        return(min(which(cumsum(tooManyRuns[,"BaseCount"])>=100.0)))
       } )   

plot(density(numRunsNeeded));rug(numRunsNeeded);abline(v=mean(numRunsNeeded));abline(v=median(numRunsNeeded),lty=2)
```

Note that you don't get 66.666 but 67.xx that is because your base count is on average going to be > 100 (the last run is not necessarily going to produce the integer you need to hit 100 exactly).

Comment: Hi Hans,The solution you provided worked perfectly!!Thanks a ton for the prompt response!You really understood the situation exactly as it is! I had another question if you could help me with it. Suppose I had 2 more rounds to do after base.What was 0.5 for base is 0.4 and 0.1 respectively for the subsequent 2 rounds,say A and B. Now, the ones that do not qualify for these 2 rounds from the base will accumulate in another new column say T.First the residuals of base to 3rd round and then from 3rd to 4th.How can I go about these?Would these need separate loops? Awaiting your valuable response..

Comment: And yes I forgot to specify, the sum for the 3rd and 4th round would be 40 and 10 respectively.

Comment: Hans, could you spare sometime to help me further with the question I had? It would be very helpful.

Comment: I am just a beginner in R really struggling hard with this one though I am sure there are many pros out here who could solve this really easily with a few smart codes. Any help from anyone would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I believe in the kindness of strangers and I am going to do you a big favor by not answering your question for you. Believe in yourself and tackle the problem: you might become better in the process. If you think this answer is useless to you, think of what will become of you if you ask other people for help at every little step. If you can understand the answer to this question, it should be obvious that can figure out a solution to your other questions.

Comment: All right sir. Its not that I did not try before I put up the question but may be I did not try as hard as I should have. Thanks a lot for your help up till now. Even if I figure out the solution, I would owe it to you for providing me the first looping solution which indeed built up my base for this experiment and also for the constructive criticism. Thanks again.